# wget 200 Webcat Access denied error

Tags: wget

I am trying to download this file from terminal but getting following error

```
sudo wget "http://indiamp3download.com/indian_movies/Gangs_Of_Wasseypur_(2012)_IndiaMp3.Com.zip"

http://indiamp3download.com/indian_movies/Gangs_Of_Wasseypur_(2012)_IndiaMp3.Com.zip
Resolving indiamp3download.com (indiamp3download.com)... 94.102.51.123
Connecting to indiamp3download.com (indiamp3download.com)|94.102.51.123|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 Webcat Access denied
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: ‘Gangs_Of_Wasseypur_(2012)_IndiaMp3.Com.zip.7’
```

Any other way or something I am missing ?

Answer (score 2):

According to the output of `wget`, the remote HTTP server returns the response code and message:

```
200 Webcat Access denied
```

This is a bit odd, because status code 200 is supposed to denote success, but the subsequent status messages contains "denied". It's also a non-standard message, because "Webcat" doesn't appear anywhere in the HTTP specification.

To summarize, the error lies not with you but with the server administrator. There's nothing, you can do about it without their help.

Answer (score -1):

The error means that your network provider doesn't allow you to download a file exceeding a particular file size. Ask your network provider to allow you to download large files.

Comment: -1 I disagree. The access denial originates from the web server, not the network provider, as can be seen by the successful server connection and not so successful HTTP response.